# Trying to perform MINUS operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform a `MINUS` operation in MySql.I have three tables:

1. one with service details
2. one table with states that a service is offered in
3. another table (based on zipcode and state) shows where this service is not offered.

I am able to get the output for those two select queries separately. But I need a combined statement that gives the output as 
'SELECT query_1  -  SELECT query_2'.

**Service_Details Table**
Service_Code(PK)  Service  Name

**Servicing_States Table**
Service_Code(FK)  State  Country   PK(Service_Code,State,Country)

**Exception Table**
Service_Code(FK)  Zipcode  State   PK(Service_Code,Zipcode,State)

Comment: what are you expecting this minus operation to do?

Answer (score 56):

MySql does not recognise **MINUS** and **INTERSECT**, these are Oracle based operations. In MySql a user can use `NOT IN` as `MINUS` (*other solutions are also there, but I liked it lot*).
Example:

```
select a.id 
from table1 as a 
where <condition> 
AND a.id NOT IN (select b.id 
                 from table2 as b 
                 where <condition>);
```

Answer (score 10):

MySQL Does not supports `MINUS` or `EXCEPT`,You can use `NOT EXISTS`, `NULL` or `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my two cents... a complex query just made it work, originally expressed with Minus and translated for MySql

With MINUS:

```
select distinct oi.`productOfferingId`,f.name 
from t_m_prod_action_oitem_fld f
     join t_m_prod_action_oitem oi 
    on f.fld2prod_action_oitem = oi.oid;
minus
select
  distinct r.name,f.name
from t_m_prod_action_oitem_fld f
     join t_m_prod_action_oitem oi 
    on f.fld2prod_action_oitem = oi.oid
     join t_m_rfs r 
    on r.name = oi.productOfferingId
     join t_m_attr a 
    on a.attr2rfs = r.oid and f.name = a.name;
```

With NOT EXISTS

```
select distinct oi.`productOfferingId`,f.name 
from t_m_prod_action_oitem_fld f
     join t_m_prod_action_oitem oi 
    on f.fld2prod_action_oitem = oi.oid
where not exists (
select
  r.name,f.name
from t_m_rfs r 
     join t_m_attr a 
    on a.attr2rfs = r.oid   
where r.name = oi.productOfferingId and f.name = a.name
```

Answer (score 2):

The tables have to have the same columns, but I think you can achieve what you are looking for with `EXCEPT`... except that `EXCEPT` only works in standard SQL! Here's how to do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Servicing_states ss WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   ( SELECT * FROM Exception e WHERE ss.Service_Code = e.Service_Code);
```

http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

**Standard SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM Servicing_States
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Exception;
```

Answer (score 1):

An anti-join pattern is the approach I typically use. That's an outer join, to return all rows from query_1, along with matching rows from query_2, and then filtering out all the rows that had a match... leaving only rows from query_1 that didn't have a match.  For example:

```
   SELECT q1.* 
     FROM ( query_1 ) q1
     LEFT
     JOIN ( query_2 ) q2 
       ON q2.id = q1.id 
    WHERE q2.id IS NULL
```

To emulate the `MINUS` set operator, we'd need the join predicate to compare all columns returned by q1 and q2, also matching NULL values.

```
       ON q1.col1 <=> q2.col2
      AND q1.col2 <=> q2.col2
      AND q1.col3 <=> q2.col3
      AND ...
```

Also, To fully emulate the `MINUS` operation, we'd also need to remove duplicate rows returned by q1. Adding the `DISTINCT` keyword would be sufficient to do that.

Comment: I get extremely poor performance on this kind of query. Clearly this is a use case where MySQL simply does not shine.

Comment: @mydoghasworms: "extremely poor performance" of a MySQL query is usually related to an inefficient (suboptimal) query plan. The query pattern  in this answer is less than ideal because it uses inline views (familiar performance issues with "derived tables"). The original question doesn't give the actual SQL text, and doesn't give an explanation (specification) of what the query should return. OP does identify some information about some tables, but the question that was asked seems to be how to get MySQL to emulate "`query1 MINUS query2`".

Comment: @mydoghasworms: I usually get reasonable execution plans and adequate performance with the anti-join pattern. (When suitable index is available, MySQL makes effective use of that index.) My personal preference would be to avoid the performance killing inline views (derived tables). I'd do a rewrite, and combine OP `query_1` and `query_2` into a single query, avoiding any derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

In case the tables are huge and are similar, one option is to save the PK to new tables. Then compare based only on the PK. In case you know that the first half is identical or so add a where clause to check only after a specific value or date .

```
create table _temp_old ( id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY )

create table _temp_new ( id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY )

### will take some time
insert into _temp_old ( id ) 
select id from _real_table_old  

### will take some time
insert into _temp_new ( id ) 
select id from _real_table_new

### this version should be much faster
select id  from _temp_old to where not exists ( select id from _temp_new tn where to.id = tn.id)

### this should be much slower
select id  from _real_table_old rto where not exists ( select id from _real_table_new rtn where rto.id = rtn.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select a1.loc from (
    select
        distinct(column) as loc
    from
        table1
    where
        condition
) as a1
where a1.loc not in (
    select b1.loc from (
        select
            distinct(column) as loc
        from
            table2
        where
            condition
    ) as b1
);
```

It will give `MINUS` functionality in MySQL.