# Combination of two SQL queries using IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT project_id 
FROM projects 
WHERE  (meta_key = "Project Name" AND meta_value LIKE '%t%' )
```

This returns

```
project_id
251
299
302
319
317
307
310
312
371
364
365
366
368
```

I have another query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT project_id
FROM tags
WHERE (tag LIKE '%t%')
```

This returns:

```
project_id
251
```

I try to combine the two statements with an `IN` statement in order to get there intersection.

```
SELECT DISTINCT project_id 
FROM projects 
WHERE (meta_key = "Project Name" AND meta_value LIKE '%t%' )
IN (SELECT DISTINCT project_id
    FROM tags
    WHERE (tag LIKE '%t%'))
```

However, I get nothing for the result.

```
project_id
```

I think I should get

```
project_id
251
```

Am I using the `IN` statement correctly here? If not which tool should I be using to accomplish this task. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397313/trying-to-perform-minus-operation-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign *project_id* to the `IN` clause expression. Right now, `IN()` evaluates the boolean logic of other `WHERE` condition and *False* or *True* will never be equivalent to a three-digit integer.

```
...
WHERE (meta_key = 'Project Name' AND meta_value LIKE '%t%' )
AND project_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT project_id
                   FROM tags
                   WHERE (tag LIKE '%t%'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response this worked. I'm having trouble understanding why this works do you have an example of how IN works in this case.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is unnecessary with `IN`.

Comment: @jackana3 ... I explain why your earlier attempt did not work. Simply reference `project_ID` in `IN` expression. And you are welcome. Glad to help.